# MPI_Type_create_resized leads to segmentation fault when the dimensionality of a subarray is greater than 2

Tags: fortran, mpi

I recently learned about `MPI_Type_create_subarray` and `MPI_Type_create_resized`, and it has been working just fine for 2-dimensional arrays. However, when I try to use the same approach for 3-dimensional arrays, I get segmentation fault.

For example, something like this works fine:

```
program test
implicit none
include 'mpif.h'

integer :: my_id, size_of_cluster, ierror
integer :: newtype, newtype_resized
integer :: intsize
integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) :: extent

call MPI_Init(ierror)
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size_of_cluster, ierror)
call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierror)

call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INT, intsize, ierror)
extent = intsize*3
call MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, (/ 6, 6 /), (/ 3, 3 /), (/ 0, 0 /), &
                              MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INT, newtype, ierror)
call MPI_Type_commit(newtype, ierror)
call MPI_Type_create_resized(newtype, 0, extent, newtype_resized)
call MPI_Type_commit(newtype_resized, ierror)

call MPI_Finalize(ierror)
end program test
```

Now, if I just add one more dimension:

```
call MPI_Type_create_subarray(3, (/ 6, 6, 6 /), (/ 3, 3, 3 /), (/ 0, 0, 0 /), &
                              MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INT, newtype, ierror)
```

then I get segmentation fault.

Interestingly enough, everything works again after this change:

```
call MPI_Type_create_subarray(3, (/ 6, 6, 6 /), (/ 1, 3, 3 /), (/ 0, 0, 0 /), &
                              MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INT, newtype, ierror)
```

At first glance, it seems like there is some kind of limit on the dimensionality of a subarray when using `MPI_Type_create_resized`. However, I doubt it, and I think that the problem lies somewhere else.
I could not find any information about a similar problem on the Internet, so I would greatly appreciate any of your thoughts on this!

Comment: If you get a segmentation fault, we need a complete [mcve] that we can try to compile and run ourselves. It is not clear if your first two snippets are such complete programs. Can we just remove the `stop`, add `end` and compile? It seems that not all variables used are declared, please use `implicit none`.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for your comment, I edited my question and added the missing parts.

Comment: Which MPI library (vendor and version) are you running?

Comment: Does it work if you add the missing error argument to the call to mpi_create_resized and use MPI_INTEGER instead of the non-standard MPI_INT? Related I would strongly recommend you USE the mpi module of even better the mpi_08 module, that would catch the error in the call to resized automatically. The include file should be considered deprecated and no longer employed.

Comment: @IanBush Thank you so much for catching the missing error argument! It was indeed the source of the problem, now it's fixed, and everything works perfectly. Very weird that it worked with this mistake for 2-dimensional arrays in the first place, now I'm curious to understand why. I'm new to the site, how should we proceed now? Do you want to write your suggestions as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: If you make a mistake in your code, especially with memory, it can cause all sort of strange effects - basically get an argument list wrong and your code could end up screwed more or less anywhere; USE THE MPI MODULE, IT WILL OFTEN CATCH THIS FOR YOU. As for the answer this is certainly effectively a duplicate of an earlier question. I'll have a look at some point to see if I can find one. You are certainly not the first person to make this mistake, and I number myself in the set!

Comment: These are all excellent points!